# Firebase Database doesn´t respond

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have no idea why, but my code isn´t working.
I want to use the Firebase Realtime Database in my Webpage, but as soon as I add Firebase stuff, executing my code does nothing at all anymore. Chrome doesn´t discover any errors in my code.
Can you tell me, why it doesn´t work. Did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much,
nicom

PS: I replaced the API Key in the code with "|" so you can´t see my API Key :)

I executed my code in Chrome and the Tryit Editor from W3Schools. Also, I tried changing the code a lot of time, but no way brought me to the goal.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.0/firebase-database.js">
  var config = {
    apiKey: "|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||",
    authDomain: "littleappsdatabase.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://littleappsdatabase.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "littleappsdatabase.appspot.com"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var database = firebase.database();
  function getTermine () {
    firebase.database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) { 
        var termine = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().calendar) || 'Keine Termine vorhanden';
      });

    return (termine);
  }
  var list = getTermine();
  document.write('<h4>', list.replace(';', '<br><br>'), '</h4>');
</script>
```

I thought that it displays the value of the given tag with a possible delay.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your question to properly format your code. Now you can clearly see that you are returning an undefined `termine` variable in the outer function `getTermine()`. This will obviously not contain the result you were looking for.

Further, I suspect that the code you are running is asynchronous, so you cannot return the value in a synchronous way. You can however create a callback function that is called as soon as the value becomes available. Like so:

```
function getTermine(callback) {
  firebase.database()
    .ref('/users/' + userId)
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) { 
      var termine = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().calendar) || 'Keine Termine vorhanden';
      callback(termine);
    });
}

getTermine(function(list) {
  document.write('<h4>', list.replace(';', '<br><br>'), '</h4>');
);
```

Hope that helps. Pay attention to the layout of your code when you are working as you can easily spot these mistakes when you correctly indent your code.